# Laravel sending new cookies for every request which eventually leads to error 431

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-sanctum

I am building a Laravel API connected to a NextJS SPA. I am using Sanctum session-based authentication.

`config/auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
        'web'    => [
            'driver'   => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'users'  => [
            'driver'   => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver'   => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ]
    ]

'providers' => [
        'users'  => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => Admin::class
        ]
    ],
```

In `config/session.php` 'encrypt' is set to `true`

These are my routes in `routes/api.php`

```
Route::get('/verify-admin-auth', [AdminController::class, 'verifyAuth']);
Route::post('/admin-login', [AdminController::class, 'authenticate']);

Route::middleware('auth:admins')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/brands', [BrandController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('/brand', [BrandController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('/brand/{brand}', [BrandController::class, 'show']);
    Route::put('/brand/{brand}', [BrandController::class, 'update']);
});
```

Now let's take an example where I delete all the cookies in my browser and access a protected route from the SPA. While accessing the route, it returns status code `401` as expected and my SPA is redirected to the login page but the response also sends a `XSRF-Token` cookie. Is that normal behavior, since I am not requesting the `sanctum/csrf-cookie` route?

[image]

Now after I login, these are the response cookies that I get:

[image]

My second question is why I keep getting `XSRF-Token` and `laravel_session` cookies with new values for every request? Shouldn't these values persist for every request?

As you can notice the Laravel response always sends 3 cookies for every request: `XSRF-Token`, `laravel_session` and one with a dynamic name. So, after every response, the `XSRF-Token`, `laravel_session` cookies' values are overwritten and a new cookie created for the one with the dynamic name. What this means is that the cookies with the dynamic names keeps adding up after every request and at some point there are too many cookies which leads to an error `431`. Then I have to manually delete the cookies in my browser so I can continue using the system.

Is there a way to get rid of that issue?

Comment: Is this something you managed to figure out?